# Throttling a C# event handler without Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, events, race-condition

I'm trying to throttle an event without using reactive extensions. I would use RX but it seems a bit heavy handed when I only need to throttle one event. Are there any problems that can occur in the following code? I'm particularly concerned about race conditions.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _eventThrottle;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _myEventSource.SomeEvent += MyEventHandler;

        _eventThrottle = new System.Timers.Timer(500) { AutoReset = false };
        _eventThrottle.Elapsed += (o, a) =>
        {
            // System.Timers.Timer runs on another thread.
            // Dispatcher puts us back on the UI thread.
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                // Handle Event
            }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
        };
    }

    private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _eventThrottle.Stop();
        _eventThrottle.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your event fires regularly every 250 ms it'll never fire.  That's not throttling behavior; throttling behavior is ignoring all requests within Xms of an already handled handler.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps throttling is the wrong word. The event is a control resize event which is raised very frequently when a user is resizing, but I only care about the final result when the resize is complete. What is a better word to describe this?